# Deploy chaincode without changing chaincodeid

Tags: hyperledger

Is there a way to deploy an update of the chaincode without changing the chaincodeid?
If I deploy changes in code, hyperledger generates new hash as chaincodeid and I loose the data created by the app.

Thanks in advance.

Sorry, more info
I'm using versión 0.6 with IBM docker images https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/fabric-images
I was also using hfc@0.6.5 in windows, but if I suscribe to the event hub inside an express application, it dies without any messaging, so now I'm using fabric starter kit with hfc@0.6.2 (but that's another question)

And more info
In https://github.com/hyperledger-archives/fabric/blob/master/docs/Setup/Chaincode-setup.md it is shown how to deploy manually the chaincode in development mode using **--peer-chaincodedev** and using -n to provide a name name instead of a path; but that is only in development mode.

Comment: Which fabric version are you using ?

Comment: in fabric v0.6 you can not update the chaincode

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to deploy an update of chaincode in the Fabric v0.6 developer preview. [Chaincode lifecycle management](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/stable/chaincode4noah.html#chaincode-lifecycle) was added in the Fabric v1.0 release.